# LibreOffice cannot find file

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, document

I wrote a really important document and saved it under documents folder. When I restarted my computer I discovered I cannot find the file in it's location. When I opened writer it tells me I need to restore the file, but when I click next it cannot find the file and says the restoration failed. What can I do?

Comment: I guess there is no point in talking about the need to keep backups (Dropbox or SpiderOak fit nicely here). Off the top of my head: did you check that you're under the correct user? And have you double-checked the location: sometimes you save in Desktop, but then look into Documents.

Comment: i created a new folder when creating my document and seems like it was deleted too.

Comment: Unless you've used `/tmp` (in which case your file is gone for good), your file is probably there somewhere. Try all possible and unlikely places.

Answer (score 2):

In a teminal use these commands which may help you find your file:

'sudo updatedb'
'sudo locate '

Example:

'sudo locate .odt'

The above will list all files on your PC with the characters '.odt' in them.  .odt being the default file extension of LibreOffice Writer.

Perhaps the document is on a USB stick which has since been removed?

Comment: You can also use `catfish` for this.